# Spring circular dependency using setters

Tags: spring, circular-dependency

I have read that to avoid circular dependencies I can use `@Autowired` on setters instead of constructors.

If so, why does this fail?

```
@Component
private static class A {
    @Autowired
    public A(B b) {
    }
}

@Component
private static class B {
    private A a;

    public B() {
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

If I define the `A` class similarly to `B`, everything is ok, but the above one should already work, so why it doesn't? I am in situation where I cannot get rid of dependency in constructor of `A` class. What can I do in this case?

EDIT:
I am using Spring 3.2.1.RELEASE

EDIT2:
My exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dependencyTest.A' defined in file [/home/adam/workspaces/testproject/target/classes/mypackage/test/DependencyTest$A.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [mypackage.test.DependencyTest$B]: : Error creating bean with name 'dependencyTest.B': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void mypackage.test.DependencyTest$B.setA(mypackage.test.DependencyTest$A); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dependencyTest.A': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dependencyTest.B': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void mypackage.test.DependencyTest$B.setA(mypackage.test.DependencyTest$A); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dependencyTest.A': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:730)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1049)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:953)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
    at mypackage.test.DependencyTest.main(DependencyTest.java:10)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dependencyTest.B': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void mypackage.test.DependencyTest$B.setA(mypackage.test.DependencyTest$A); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dependencyTest.A': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:891)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:834)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:795)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:723)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void mypackage.test.DependencyTest$B.setA(mypackage.test.DependencyTest$A); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dependencyTest.A': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dependencyTest.A': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:327)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:891)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:834)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:558)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: It would be great if you point exact error for your case.

Comment: @Taky I have added the stacktrace

Comment: Have you tried without using static inner classes?  I am thinking top level classes...

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild Yes, I have. This is only a simplified example of what I experienced using top level classes in my project.

Comment: BTW I have reported an issue in Spring Jira as I believe this is a bug (however @RyanStewart provided a good and simple workaround)

Comment: Have you tried `@Autowired @Lazy`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think Spring just isn't quite clever enough to realize that this kind of relationship has to be loaded in a specific order to avoid looking like an unresolvable circular reference. It typically handles circular references by caching singleton instances after constructing them but before fully populating them so that it can inject the instance where needed, even if it's not populated yet, since it knows it will finish setting it up later.

What's happening is that it's trying to create the A first, but it can't even construct one without a B, so it can't cache an A instance. Then it tries to create a B and sees that it needs an A, but it knows it's in the process of creating the A but doesn't have a cached instance to use for the dependency, so it fails. You need to force it to create the B instance first with something like a `@DependsOn("dependencyTest.B")`. Then the singleton caching can take place because a B can be constructed without needing an A, so the unpopulated B instance will be available when creating the A.

Comment: That's good workaround. However you have mistaken the order, in my example it would be `@DependsOn("b")` or even `@DependsOn("dependencyTest.B") (if you looked into the stacktrace you would see these are inner classes), added next to `@Component` annotation of `A` class

Comment: And additionally, as I have mentioned already in a [bug that I had reported](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10349) the reversed situation does work without problem. So if you change your answer according to my comment above, I can accept it as a workaround for this particular case (unless someone provides me with something better :) )

Comment: Yep, sorry about the wrong name in the `@DependsOn`. It's fixed now. I've voted up that bug because it seems like something Spring should be able to detect and handle.

Answer (score 2):

The beans are instantiated first, then injected into each other. That's why you are facing this situation. When `A` is being instantiated, it needs `B`.

Using setters, instead of constructors, would resolve this issue, as the instantiation phase is done without adding dependencies.

Comment: One side uses setter injection, so this isn't an unresolvable problem. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15194949/839646).

Comment: Did I say it is "unresolvable"? As he asked, I just explained the problem and why it occurs.